# Convert HTML files to txt preserving ordered/unordered list with AspNet- Htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to convert from html to .txt with HTML AGILITY PACK.
I would like to retain the numberings or letterings from the ordered or unordered list to keep the same rendering.

Given a HTML like :

```
<h1> Title </h1>
<h2> Sub Title </h2>
<ol>
  <li style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"> First element </li>
  <li style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"> Second element </li>
  <li style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"> Third element </li>
</ol>
<h3> Diferent title</h3>
<ol>
  <li style="list-style-type: lower-roman;"> First element </li>
  <li style="list-style-type: lower-roman;"> Second element </li>
</ol>

<h3> Diferent title</h3>
<p> Some text </p>
<ol>
  <li> First element </li>
  <li> Second element </li>
</ol>

<h3> Unordered list title</h3>
<ul>
  <li> First element </li>
  <li> Second element </li>
</ul>
```

I cannot find the way. I tried with this:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

    var htmlBody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
    var lists = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ol"); //todas las <ol>

    
     foreach (HtmlNode node in lists)
        {
        var elementInList = node.SelectNodes(".//li").Count; 
         Console.WriteLine("elementInList "+ elementInList);    
         
         for ( int i=0; i < elementInList;i++){
         
             Console.WriteLine( i+1 + ". "+ node.SelectNodes(".//li")[i].InnerHtml);
         }
```

But I do want it to appear in the text like that, to substitute the < li > in order to have the position like " 1. First Element" (not in the console)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Read the [docs](https://html-agility-pack.net/documentation), start to code something and try to divide your problems into smaller sub-problems. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, but we're happy to help with clear problems.

Comment: Thank you @Maio290, you are right. I edited it and added more information about what I tried

Comment: Can you show us what you want the output to look like, given the input HTML you have in your question?  It looks to me like the code you have already preserves the numbering of the ordered lists, so I'm not sure what you are asking.